# Uninstallable Applications

Tags: windows-vista, uninstall

I'm on Windows Vista Home Edition right now, and have tried using Daemon Tools Lite to mount a disk image. Once I was done I decided it was just a waste of space and tried uninstalling it. However, when I tried to uninstall it from the control panel, it crashed and gave me a blue screen saying something like "dumping memory onto hard drive."

The next day I tried and it gave me the save result.

Are there any programs that can bypass the uninstaller that comes with Daemon Tools Lite, and just uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Short explanations](http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/f26/how-remove-daemon-tools-v4-6992/) in the Daemon Tools forum...
2. Take a look at this: [How to Completely Uninstall DAEMON Tools Lite](http://howto-uninstall.windowsuninstaller.org/how-to-completely-uninstall-daemon-tools-lite-for-microsoft-windows-7/) (For Microsoft Windows 7). The site gives many way to uninstall Daemon Tool Lite for W 7 but may be this also works for Vista...
3. If any of these suggestions works try [TotalUninstall](http://www.martau.com/) (shareware but you can use it free for 30 days!). Reinstall Daemon Tool Lite monitored by TotalUninstall. When the monitored installation will be finished, use TotalUninstall again and completely uninstall Daemon Tool Lite.

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Set a manual Restore point, then [Use AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) (driver tab) to disable the daemon tools driver from loading at startup, restart and try to remove it again.